# Adding _links ,_refs to Spring application using hateos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I have a spring boot service article. I am using spring data rest and mongoDB. I am overriding findAll() method in custom controller. But in the response i am missing _links and page details. I am looking for a way to get **_links and page info** when findAll() method is overridden in custom controller.

Expected response:

```
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/article"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/articles"
        },
        "search": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/articles/search"
        },
        "page": {
            "size": 20,
            "totalElements": 61,
            "totalPages": 5,
            "number": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add spring-boot-starter-hateoas dependency and perform the changes accordinglyhttps://www.baeldung.com/spring-hateoas-tutorial. Please check

Comment: show us your relevant code so that we can understand better to help you

Comment: You need to make sure to return the appropriate representation. (Specify your exact version of Spring HATEOAS, since this changed dramatically in v1.0.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding below dependency in pom.xml or relevant gradle dependency in build.gradle

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And extend model object using **extends ResourceSupport**